# How to parse the password hash hashed by Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, password-hash

I want to migrate my users from my application to an external SSO. I want my users to keep their existing passwords, so I'd like to retrieve the hashed password and provide it to the SSO application. The algorithm is the same on both sides (pbkdf2-sha256) so it's supposed to work.

Thus I need to be able to retrieve the salt and hashed password from the entry in the database.

My application uses Spring Security.

It seems that I need to do this manually, as the interface PasswordEncoder, which Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder implements, does not provide a way to retrieve the initial elements from the stored value.

What would be the correct way to achieve this ?

Thanks

edit:

Here is my code

```
Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder encoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder("", 27500, 512);
String encoded = encoder.encode("password");
System.out.println(encoded); // prints the hex encoded hashed password: 2a319aaf0252d77e671cf1b074f149f7eed1b362afb47bef84e9b01a8140b26a733cd22df007d68668915c7bd51af9eefda1662216a184fa7eb034c176ce9518fc83f3fd935a2d3d
final byte[] digested = Hex.decode(encoded);
byte[] salt = EncodingUtils.subArray(digested, 0, 7);
byte[] password = EncodingUtils.subArray(digested, 8, digested.length);
System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(salt))); // prints KjGarwJS134=
System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(password))); // prints HPGwdPFJ9+7Rs2KvtHvvhOmwGoFAsmpzPNIt8AfWhmiRXHvVGvnu/aFmIhahhPp+sDTBds6VGPyD8/2TWi09
```

If I then go to [this website](https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp) and enter the following values:

- master password: password
- salt: KjGarwJS134=
- iteration: 27500
- dkLen: 512
- PBE Ciphers: sha256

Then I would expect the output to match the last output of my code, but this isn't the case.

Comment: @Vladimir I think they want access to the RAW hashed (but encrypted) password bits. And transfer that information to the new SSO service (this means that the users would not have to change passwords).

Comment: Vladimir, GhostCat is right, I just need to copy the raw password to a new software, which stores it differently (base64 vs hex, etc, ...) but uses the same hash algorithm. So basically I need to retrieve the salt from the stored entry.

Comment: @sroup I guess there is something wrong/different with the online tool. I tried your  code and used the salt and password to generate a new hash and the result was equal. So the salt is correct. Althought, I set `encoder.setAlgorithm(SecretKeyFactoryAlgorithm.PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256);` to use your desired algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously cannot get the password back from the hash, but I don't think you're asking that. Here's how you would do it:

1. First check if it is base64. If so, take your string and base64-decode it, turning it into a byte array. (The default is just hex nibbles, i.e. option 2).
2. If it wasn't, then it's just hex nibbles. You can tell; if the entire thing consists solely of digits and the letters a-f, it's this, otherwise it's #1 (base64). Parsing hex nibbles back to a byte array is fairly trivial; toss every 2 characters through parseInt: `Integer.parseInt(in.substring(x, x + 2), 0x10);` - the 0x10 at the end is important.
3. The byte array obtained with this is the salt and the hash, concatenating, in that order. By default, the salt would be 8 bytes, but this is all configurable in spring. So, lop off the first 8 bytes  from the array - that's your salt.
4. The rest is 'just' the raw hash.

Comment: I didn't change the default configuration, so it's indeed 8 bytes and hex nibbles. However I wasn't using the algorithm you're describing to decode it. I was using org.springframework.security.Hex.decode() which seemed to be what Spring Security is using. Can you please elaborate on that, and what is `in` and `x` ?

Comment: Hex.decode should work too. 'in' is the string you get from the db. x is the index. Hex.encode just turns, say, byte sequence 0xAA 0x9F into the string "AA9F". Hex.decode undoes that; the source of Hex.decode would do something like `byte[] decode(String in) {byte[] out = new byte[in.length() / 2]; for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) out[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(in.substring(i*2, i*2 + 2), 0x10); }`

Comment: Well I guess I have a bug in my code then because I'm using your algorithm and this decode function, but it doesn't work. I will add a piece of code to show you what I'm doing. Do you confirm that, once I get the salt and password, if I base64 encode them and provide the password and base64-salt to [this website](https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp) for example, then I should get the base64-password, provided that I enter the same options ?

Comment: @sroup - no, you CANNOT GET THE PASSWORD from a hash, that's the point of a hash! - take the salt, use the salt and the password (and sending passwords to a website you don't control is... well, it makes my skin itch) to generate the hash using PBKDF2-SHA256. THen, the salt + that hash should match what you get by applying my algorithm.

Comment: you keep saying 'raw password'. Either you're confusing matters, or it is you who are confused. A hash is _NOT_ the password. It is NOT POSSIBLE to go from 'hash' back to 'password', that is the whole point of them. Until you untangle this mess in your brain you won't figure this out.